# Proof of $ x (x+1) $ is an even number by contradiction proof method

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $ x(x+1) $ is always even by the **method of contradiction**.

I assumed $ x(x+1) = 2k + 1 $ as an odd integer where $ k $ is an integer

Add $1$ to both sides, we get $ x (x+1) + 1 = 2k + 1 + 1 $

$ x (x+1) + 1 = 2(k + 1) $

that is $2$ divides left hand side. How can I get a contradiction? Please guide.

Answer (score 4):

Assume the $x(x+1)$ is odd, then all its prime factors are odd. So if $x$ is odd, $x+1$ is not: Contradiction...

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to consider two cases:
$x$ is even, say $x=2l$, then $4l^2+2l+1=2(k+1)$, which implies $2|1$, a contradiction. Can you do the other case ($x$ is odd, put $x=2l+1$ and plug it in).

Answer (score 3):

In the contradiction use this: If $ab$ be an odd number then $a$ and $b$ both are odd numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a strange question as the result is very easy to prove without using contradiction.  But anyway. . .

Here is an outline of a possible proof.  You didn't say what the numbers $x$ are so let's assume you want to prove it for positive integers.  Suppose that $x(x+1)$ is not always even: that is, it is odd for some $x$.  Choose the smallest such $x$.  Since $x(x+1)$ is odd, $x(x+1)-2x$ is odd minus even and therefore also odd, that is,
$$(x-1)x$$
is odd.  But this contradicts the minimality of $x$.

There are a couple of details still to be filled in, see how you go.

Comment: Very nice, although it doesn't work for $x=1$ (Since $x-1$ wouldn't be a positive integer)

Comment: @user138676 that was one of the details I left for the reader.  In fact, this shows that $x$ **must be** $1$, so by assumption $2$ is odd, which is a contradiction again.